# Search/iterate through QListWidget and display results

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to allow the user to search through a QListWidget that contains file names. I've tried several things with no success. No error messages either.

This is my search function that gets called when pressing a button. It uses the string the user put into "search_field" widget. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    def search_files(self):
    items = self.listWidget.findItems(self.search_field.text(), QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
    if items:
        results = '\n'.join(str(item)for item in items)
    else:
        results = 'Found nothing'
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information, 'Search Results', results)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need to add `messagebox.exec()` to your code. `findItems()` returns a list of  items. If the user should see the matching file names and not the items, use `str(item.text())`. here a rewrite:

```
def search_files(self):
    items = self.listWidget.findItems(self.search_field.text(), QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
    if items:
        results = '\n'.join(str(item)for item in items) # or str(item.text())
    else:
        results = 'Found nothing'
    mb = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information, 'Search Results', results)
    mb.exec()
```

Comment: Just got it working, your solution helped me. Thanks you so much!!